# Removing elements from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web

i'm having trouble removing elements from `lists`. When an `e-mail` is send I want to remove from `urls[]` and `prices[]` the relative elements.

Ex. if email has: like a `url` an `Iphone X` and like a `price 500€` and it had been sent, i want to `"rewrite"` the elements in `urls[]` and `prices[]` lists removing `iphone's url and 500€`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time

#   https://www.amazon.it/Corsair-Vengeance-Memorie-Desktop-Prestazioni/dp/B0143UM4TC
#   https://www.amazon.it/AMD-Ryzen-5-3600-Processori/dp/B07STGGQ18
#   https://www.amazon.it/Apple-iPhone-Grigio-Siderale-Ricondizionato/dp/B07985C44N

urls = []
prices=[]
all_product = []
n = int(input("Inserisci il numero di prodotti: "))

#agginge il link da controllare
print("\nInserisci i link:")
for i in range(0, n): 
    link = str(input()) 
    urls.append(link)    

#aggiunge il realtivi prezzi ai link
print("\nInserisci i prezzi:")
for i in range(0, n): 
    money = int(input()) 
    prices.append(money) 

#headers per i diversi motori di ricerca
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}

def check_price():
    for url, price in zip(urls, prices):
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)    
        try:
            products = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
            fix_string = products.replace(",", ".")      
            converted_price = float(fix_string[0:5])
            all_product.append(converted_price)
            money_saved=converted_price-price
            if (converted_price<=price): 
                 #send email
                remove_link=str(url)
                remove_price=price
                if(urls.index(remove_link)&prices.index(remove_price)):
                    urls.pop((urls.index(remove_link)))
                    prices.pop(prices.index(remove_price))
         except AttributeError:
            print ("Prezzo non trovato, controlla se il prodotto ha un prezzo esposto")
    print(all_product)
```

Comment: Where in this code are you attempting to do this, and what specific "trouble" are you having doing it?

Comment: i tried to  use pop(), in if condition, but it makes this error:  'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: you mean `urls.pop(url)` not `urls.pop[url]`

Comment: yes, @alaniwi. I have now edited the post

Comment: *Now* what is the "trouble" you are having?

Comment: no problem. i've found a way. it wasn't so difficult.

Comment: I don't understand why you remove it from list if you don't use this list later. And in Python removing from list when you iterate this list can makes problem because it may automatically move other elements and `for`-loop can skip some element. It is better to create new list for elements which you want to keep and `append()` them.

Comment: @furas my idea is that: I have two lists, the first is for the link of the product I would like to buy and the second is for the price I am willing to pay.
For example if an iphone costs 500 € but I want to pay it 450 € every x hours this code checks the price of the iPhone using the relative link in the urls list. When it reaches € 450, it sends me an email notifying me and subsequently removes the url of the iPhone from the urls list and also my price. So as to avoid further equal mails.

Comment: Python doesn't like to remove from list which is used in `for`. And we usually create empty list before `for`-loop (`keep_urls = []`), and inside `for`-loop we append to this list keeped element `keep_urls.append(url)`, and after loop we assign new list to old variable `urls = keep_urls`. Eventually we duplicate list which we use in `for` - `for url, price in zip(urls.copy(), prices.copy()):` and rest is the same `urls.pop(...)`, `prices.pop(...)`. BTW instead of `urls.pop(urls.index(url))` you can use `ulrs.remove(url)`

Comment: BTW: instead of `&` you should use `and` - because `&` is for bits operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python it is not good idea to remove from list which is used in `for ... in ....` because when you remove element then other elements are moved  (so next element is in place of removed element) but `for` doesn't know it and it jumps to next element on list and it skip element which was moved to place of removed element.

Better before loop create empty list (`keep_urls = []`), inside loop append to this list elements which you want to keep (`keep_urls.append(url)`), and after loop assing this list to old variable (`urls = keep_urls`). After that you can run it all again and it will use list without removed element.

This code shows how I see it.

BTW: because adding data using `input()` is long and borring so I added code which read data from files.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time

# --- functions ---

def ask_for_data():
    urls = []
    prices = []

    n = int(input("Inserisci il numero di prodotti: "))

    #agginge il link da controllare
    print("\nInserisci i link:")

    for i in range(n): 
        link = input()
        urls.append(link)    

    #aggiunge il realtivi prezzi ai link
    print("\nInserisci i prezzi:")

    for i in range(n): 
        money = input()
        prices.append(money) 

    return urls, prices

def read_data():
    with open('urls.txt') as fh:
        text = fh.read()
        urls = text.split('\n')

    with open('prices.txt') as fh:
        text = fh.read()
        prices = text.split('\n')

    return urls, prices

def write_data(urls, prices):
    with open('urls.txt', 'w') as fh:
        text = "\n".join(urls)
        fh.write(text)

    with open('prices.txt', 'w') as fh:
        text = "\n".join(prices)
        fh.write(text)

def send_email(url, price, converted_price):
    #money_saved = converted_price-price
    print('TODO: send mail with', url, price, converted_price)

# --- main ---

# - start -
#urls, prices = ask_for_data()
urls, prices = read_data()

#headers per i diversi motori di ricerca
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
}

while True:

    # - before loop -
    keep_urls = []
    keep_prices = []
    all_products = []

    # - loop -
    for url, price in zip(urls, prices):
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        #print(r.status_code)
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text(strip=True)    
        try:
            products = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
            fix_string = products.replace(",", ".")      
            converted_price = float(fix_string[0:5])

            all_products.append(converted_price)

            if converted_price <= price: 
                send_email(url, price, converted_price)
            else:
                keep_urls.append(url)
                keep_prices.append(price)

         except AttributeError as ex:
            print('Ex:', ex)
            print("Prezzo non trovato, controlla se il prodotto ha un prezzo esposto")

    # - loop -
    urls = keep_urls
    prices = keep_prices

    print(all_products)

    time_sleep(60)

# - end -
write_data(urls, prices)
```